# SCTP_DARN for remote host

Tags: command-line, networking, vpn

In the same Ubuntu pc, I can run this command easily

- To listen, I run it in one terminal:

  ```
  sctp_darn -H :: -P 1234 -l
  ```
- To send, I run in another terminal window:

  ```
  sctp_darn -H :: -P 2345 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1234 -s`
  ```

From sender to receiver terminal, I can send messages and can capture 4 way handshaking in `wireshark` on the loopback address.

But for me now situation is I want to do the same test for remote computer. Another host would inside my network or situated behind another network and connected via VPN. In this case, I run the following commands:

- To listen I run it in one terminal:

  ```
  sctp_darn -H 10.0.0.29 -P 1234 -l
  ```
- To send I run in another pc:

  ```
  sctp_darn -H 10.0.0.28 -P 2345 -h 10.0.0.29 -p 1234 -s
  ```

It's very interesting, if it's in the same network, another Ubuntu PC, on `wireshark`, I see only init & init ACK not the 4 way handshake completes.

For VPN's case, if 2 of my computers are connected through a VPN and run the same command, I see only 'init' transmits but no 'init ACK'.

Why this happens? Is this `SCTP_DARN` tool entirely developed to check for loopback address?